# Access all printers from asp.net web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am wondering if i can access a list of all installed printers from an asp.net web api project.
I have searched online for this information, but can only see articles pointing me to windows form implementation.

Comment: Do you mean printers installed on your webserver? Since asp.net is backend technology and running on *server* - you can't get list of *clientside* printers using it...

Comment: @AndyKorneyev yes i mean server side

Comment: then it doesn't matter - will it be Winforms or ASP.NET - both are using the same approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others mentioned you will only get a list of printers ***installed on the server***. Since the code is executed on the server **it will not know anything about the clients setup**. If you want the installed printers on the server, then here's how you do it.

```
public class PrinterController : ApiController
{
        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult Get()
        {
            var result = System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters;
            return Ok(result);
        }
}
```

Output will be something like:

```
[
"Send to OneNote 2010",
"Microsoft XPS Document Writer",
"Microsoft Print to PDF",
"Fax",
"\\\\prntServer\Printer1"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

From a web application you can access the printers installed on the server on which the application is running. For security reasons you don't have access to the list of printers on the client machines. In order to do that you will need some plugin or desktop application that your customers need to install.